# Should I create multiple controllers or a single controller with multiple actions to handle more detailed responses?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

This is a question about web api design. Let's say I have an method that returns a city and city properties, like population, FIPS code, and region. There are more properties, often 20+.

In some cases, I'll submit a FIPS code and expect a city name to be returned. Other times, I'll submit a FIPS code and expect a few other properties to be returned (maybe region and population).

My question is, how should I build my controllers and actions for these scenarios? Should I have one controller, named City, and a series of methods to return exactly what I need or should I use multiple controllers?

I'm fairly new to web api design but it feels cleaner to have a single controller. My thoughts are a controller, named City, with appropriately named actions, like GetNameAndPopulationFromFipsCode() or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The resource is the same so really it would normally be the same controller.

I see 2 natural ways to implement this:

1. Content-negotiation
2. client to pass an optional parameter to get a full viewmodel

First is more RESTful but can be a bit of pain, considering current key-based conneg in Web API.

Second is easier to implement:

```
// almost pseudocode !!
// called by /api/City/123?extended=true
public City Get(int id, bool? extended)
{
   ExtendedCity city = GetCity(id);
   return extended.HasValue && extended.Value ? MapTo(city) : city;
}

// ----

public class City
{
   ...
}

public class ExtendedCity : City
{
   ...
}
```

## UPDATE

As @Darrel pointed out, query string parameter changes the resource. **But in terms of resource organisation, it maintains the hierarchy** and that is why is the preferred approach.

Comment: `/api/City/123?extended=true` and `/api/City/123?extended=false` are two distinct resources because they have different identifiers and return different content.  I would still use the same controller handle both though.

Comment: @DarrelMiller but it maintains the resource hierarchy.